# SQL Function causes an error

Tags: sql-function

I'm a newbie in SQL Coding and have some problems with my function shown below

```
 CREATE FUNCTION C84F.NUMTODATE(inputDecimal DECIMAL(8)) 
   RETURNS DECIMAL (8, 0) 
   LANGUAGE SQL 

   Return CHAR (date(char(inputDecimal * 1000000)), EUR);
```

When I use this function I get an error `Sign in the CAST-Argument are invalid`. Any opinions or solutions please?

Best Regards
Peter

Comment: specify the database are you using

Comment: im using a DB2 Database running on a IBM iSeries Platform